# Maven Java EE project

Tags: maven, java

Подскажите номер проекта в mvn arhetype:generate такой, что-бы было создано три директории 
[poject]-ear,
[project]-ejb,
[project]-web,
и соответственно 4 pom файла по одному для каждой части и один общий.
Спасибо

Comment: Напоминает: подскажите пин код карты хде бабки лежат. Хе-хе...

Comment: Ну почему-же. Там 700+ проектов. А такой 100% есть, просто я номер не помню.

Comment: нашел 534 -  remote -> org.jboss.spec.archetypes:jboss-javaee6-ear-webapp (An archetype that generates a starter Java EE 6 webapp project for JBoss AS 7. The project is an EAR, with an EJB-JAR and WAR)